# Linux module __must_check annotation

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning about Linux kernel module development. I read articles and tutorials, and I found a site which supplies source code for a simple char device.

In the code a `__must_check` is used for one function.

Here is the prototype:

```
__must_check int register_device(void);
```

This is the function:

```
int register_device(void)
{
  int result = 0;

  printk( KERN_NOTICE "Simple-driver: register_device() is called." );

  result = register_chrdev( 0, device_name, &simple_driver_fops );
  if( result < 0 )
  {
     printk( KERN_WARNING "Simple-driver:  can\'t register character device with errorcode = %i", result );
     return result;
  }

  device_file_major_number = result;
  printk( KERN_NOTICE "Simple-driver: registered character device with major number = %i and minor numbers 0...255"
              , device_file_major_number );

  return 0;
}
```

What is the utility of `__must_check`? This is the only code I found that used this.

Comment: So ok, but what use is it ? @ Danh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__must_check` is defined as:

```
#define __must_check __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
```

Quotes from [Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes)

> The `warn_unused_result` attribute causes a warning to be emitted if a caller of the function with this attribute does not use its return value. This is useful for functions where not checking the result is either a security problem or always a bug, such as `realloc`.

This is also applied to [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#nodiscard-warn-unused-result-clang-warn-unused-result-gnu-warn-unused-result) and [Intel compiler](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/compilers/intel_linux_compiler_compatibility_with_gnu_compilers.pdf).

This macro asks compiler to issue a warning if the return value is not used. This is important with function return value to indicate success or failure like `scanf`, `printf`, or function return memory like `malloc`, `realloc`.